# Firefox never resolving navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, promise, webcam

I am trying to use the new Promise-based WebRTC/Media tools, to get feedback if the user allowed access to the camera and/or microphone as documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

The following code-snippet, simply injected with the browser's developer tools, does never fullfill the Promise on Firefox when access is granted, yet on Chrome it works as expected.

(tested with Firefox 53 32-bit, Chrome 59 64-bit)

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        "audio": true, 
        "video": true
    })
      .then(() => console.log("OK!"))
      .catch(() => console.log("NOPE"))
```

It appears that the Promise is pending forever.

Steps to reproduce:

1. open any https encrypted page (so firefox doesnt complain about that)
2. open the developer tools, get to the console
3. paste the code snippet from above
4. allow camera/microphone access in the popup
5. nothing

Is this a bug in Firefox or is something wrong with the code snippet?
To comply with the MDN documentation, i've also tried to use the good'ol functions instead of ES6 arrow functions - with the same effect.

Comment: Testing in Firefox 52 and the above snippet works fine, will test in 53 now too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disabling all addons (especially NoScript - even after setting "scripts globally allowed" to true) it appears to run just fine.

Sorry for the unnecessary question then, i guess, and thanks for reconfirming me, that the problem was not Firefox itself, so got on the right track to find the solution!

Comment: Also check this "issue" on Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250070/getusermedia-doesnt-trigger-error-callback-when-you-choose-not-now-in-firefox. If the user selects "not now" or closes the screen selection popup, the promise never returns either. This is a bit annoying, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fine in Firefox 53.0.3. The output I get is as follows:

[image: Firefox 53 OK]

Comment: Thank you for checking! Brought me on the right track!